# How can I prevent any cmd prompt from closing until I do so manually?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have this cmd prompt about 4 times a day.
I think it accesses consent.exe since that program seems to be the last one used by it.
I used ExecutedProgramsList to get that info.
I think it might be doing something dodgy, no unusual traffic seen but still bugs me.

How can I prevent any cmd prompt from closing until I do so manually?

Comment: I've assumed you're using a *Windows* OS, because `consent.exe` is the UI tool that asks you if you want to grant software some sort of elevated privilege. You need a tool called [*procmon.exe*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) - make sure it is running before the application starts again, and you will receive an in-depth view of what it's up to. Feel free to edit your question with more detail when you have it. In my opinion, this question is on topic, as observing pre-existing potentially unwanted software on hosts is very much an infosec task.